# How to connect postgresql PostGIS from remote client?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to connect my PostGIS database from a remote client but receive the error:

> **connection to server at "192.168.X.X" port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?**

I am using a private IPv4 address so I am putting X here.

When I connect my client to the local server my setting is as follows:

- Two machines (server and client) with different **IPv4 address** and the same **IPv4 DNS servers**. Result, connection.

When I connect my client to the remote server my setting is as follows:

- Two machines with different **IPv4 address**, but now different **IPv4 DNS servers**. Result, fails.

On both the server and client machine the **postgresql.conf** file is configured as follows:

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                            # comma-separated list of addresses;
                            # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                            # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                 # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100       # (change requires restart)
```

On both the server and client machine the **pg_hba.conf** file is configured as follows:

```
TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS          METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local            all       all                          md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host            all        all        0.0.0.0/0         md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host            all        all        ::1/128           md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication        all                          md5
host    replication        all      127.0.0.1/32        md5
host    replication        all        ::0/0             md5
```

I also have my **Windows Firewall** rules for both the inbound and outbound to accept port **5432**, on both the client and server machines.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "another WiFi"? I'm assuming you've confirmed that you can ping the server from the client machine? What happens if you try to telnet to 5432?

Comment: Pinging fails. Here are the results: **Pinging 192.168.X.X with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.0.0.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.0.0.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.0.0.2: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.X.X:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),**

Comment: Looks like you have 2 different networks that can't access each other. I think your postgres setup is fine, you'll need to resolve the network issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try changing your pg_hba.conf
2. Get your correct network and subnet mask like this:

```
## IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             192.168.0.0/16            trust
```

3. restart the postgree

Comment: On the server or client machine?

Comment: I don't think making `pg_hba.conf` more restrictive for remote connections should be the first step here.